# Class level validation issue

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm trying validation a couple of fields. If both contain invalid characters I need to output a single error message.

I'm trying to use class level validation. However I'm running into an NoSuchElement Exception when running the unit tests.

The class being validated:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@TwoFieldPattern(accountNumber = "accountNumber", sortCode = "sortCode")
public class AccountDetails {

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[-0-9]*$", message="Fields contain invalid characters: account number '${validatedValue}'")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[-0-9]*$", message="Fields contain invalid characters: sort code '${validatedValue}'")
    @NotBlank
    private String sortCode;

    public AccountDetails() {}

    public String getSortCode() {
        return sortCode;
    }

    public void setSortCode(String sortCode) {
        this.sortCode = sortCode;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
}
```

The validation classes:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = TwoFieldPatternValidator.class)
public @interface TwoFieldPattern {

    String message() default "Fields contain invalid characters: account number '${validatedValue.accountNumber}', sort code '${validatedValue.sortCode}";

    String accountNumber();

    String sortCode();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class TwoFieldPatternValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TwoFieldPattern, Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object obj, ConstraintValidatorContext cvc) {
        AccountDetails account = (AccountDetails) obj;
        return (!account.getAccountNumber().matches("^[-0-9]*$")&& !account.getSortCode().matches("^[-0-9]*$"));
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        String errorMessage = ex.getBindingResult()
                .getFieldErrors()
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .map(FieldError::getDefaultMessage)
                .get();

        final BankDetailsValidationModel validationResult = new BankDetailsValidationModel(false, false, errorMessage, "");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body(validationResult);
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at uk.co.cdl.account.bankdetailsvalidation.service.controller.ExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(ExceptionHandler.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:412) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:140) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:79) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1298) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1110) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-03-07 11:26:04.187  WARN 21456 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<uk.co.cdl.account.bankdetailsvalidation.model.BankDetailsValidationModel> uk.co.cdl.account.bankdetailsvalidation.service.controller.BankDetailsValidatorController.validate(uk.co.cdl.account.bankdetailsvalidation.model.AccountDetails): [Error in object 'accountDetails': codes [TwoFieldPattern.accountDetails,TwoFieldPattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [accountDetails.,]; arguments []; default message [],accountNumber,sortCode]; default message [Fields contain invalid characters: account number '15764273', sort code '938063]] ]

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :422
Actual   :400
```

Comment: Have you tried [`..bindingResult.getAllErros()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#getAllErrors--)?

Comment: ...and at least for debugging BindingResult.- `getErrorCount, hasErrors, hasFieldErrors, hasGlobalErrors` seem useful. (... maybe you'll find, that `Error:getDefaultMessage` is better/more appropriate/more general than `FieldError:...`

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I’m still seeing `((ViolationFieldError)((java.util.LinkedList)((BeanPropertyBindingResult)ex.bindingResult).errors).get(0)).violation = Cannot cast 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter$ViolationObjectError' to 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter$ViolationFieldError` In ExceptionHander. And `((ViolationFieldError)((java.util.LinkedList)((BeanPropertyBindingResult)ex.bindingResult).errors).get(0)).violation = Cannot find local variable 'ex'` In TwoFieldPatternValidator.

Comment: "Cannot cast" (re-read my 2nd comment): replace `FieldError:getDefaultMessage` by 
 `Error:getDefaultMessage`. "Cannot find local variable 'ex'" is somewhat strange/unexpected...

Comment: ..for the posted code" (fixed it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you set up your "class validator" correct so far, the exception stack trace points you to the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid()` method - the invocation of (`Optional.`)`get`, which lets assume, that `getFieldErrors()` is empty.

Since it is a "class vlaidator" it is not provided by `fieldErrors`, but we "get more lucky" with `allErrors` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#getAllErrors--)) ...

This leads you to a:

> Cannot cast 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter$ViolationObjectError' to 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter$ViolationFieldError

Which can be fixed by replacing `FieldError:getDefaultMessage` with `Error:getDefaultMessage`. (+ fix imports)

> Cannot find local variable 'ex'

Is not consistent with the original post ... maybe you broke something while refactoring. (Compiler message is equivalent to "variable 'ex' not declared".)

Comment: Thaks! I had completely missed that class validators does not have field errors.  Big help!